# Как обработать нажатия на стрелки С++

Tags: c++

Пишу простенькую игру и хочу сделать движение на стрелки. Пытаюсь словить нажатую клавишу через _getch(). С его помощью ничего не получается, так как при нажатии на любую стрелку переменная инициализируется одним и тем же числом 224. Что я могу делать не так, и какие есть еще варианты (сложно не надо)

```
int a = _getch();
cout << a;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для стрелок (и некоторых других не буквенно-цифровых клавиш) генерируется два события - c кодом символа `224 (0xE0)` или нулём - в первом, и `72` для стрелки вверх и т.д. во втором (в Windows и DOS).

Т.е., поймав `0xE0`, нужно ещё раз сделать `_getch()`

```
int a = _getch();
if (a == 0xE0 || a == 0) 
   a = _getch();
cout << a;
```

Вот [нашёл:](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/078sfkak(v=vs.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

> When reading a function key or an arrow key, each function must be
>   called twice; the first call returns 0 or 0xE0, and the second call
>   returns the actual key code.

Comment: Получается пользователю надо будет по 2 раза нажимать кнопку?

Comment: Нет, одно нажатие даёт набор из двух кодов клавиш.

Comment: Возможно я не прав, там первое событие означает что-то типа "Нажата функциональная клавиша", а второе событие уже несёт в себе код клавиши... Кажется так, или я с паскалем путаю...

Comment: @zcorvid Всё верно. И в досовском Паскале то же самое приходилось делать, поскольку так клавиатура генерирует коды.

Comment: @MBo прошу Вас добавить, что это ответ в Win32, ибо в Linux нужно ncurses

Comment: @Andrey Не уверен, что нужно. ncurses- лишь одна из библиотек.

Comment: @MBo ну в любом случае conio - не стандарт)